# How to combine these 2 SQL command into one?

Tags: sql, ms-access, asp-classic

I want to create a report that show both yearly income and expense together at the same time. Since I'm so naive about sql, i can do only one at a time. However I found out it would take a lot of time to display my report if I want to generate this report in monthly basis. So could you please help me combine this 2 sql ? thank you..

my current sqls are..
income sql

```
select sum(tbt.bill_total) as bill_total,
       iif(sum_vat_total is null, 0, sum_vat_total) as vat_total,
       iif(sum_vat_total is null, 0, sum_vat_total) + sum(bill_total) as sum_of_all,
       month(showndate) as [month]
from tbl_bill_total tbt
    left join (select sum(vat_total) as sum_vat_total, month(showndate) as [month]
               from tbl_vat_bill_total
               where if_paid = true
                 and year([showndate]) =" & current_year & "
               group by month(showndate)) tvt on tvt.month = month(tbt.showndate)
where year([showndate]) =" & current_year & "
group by month(showndate), sum_vat_total
```

for expense

```
SELECT Sum(tbl_expense.exp_amt) AS SumOfexp_amt,
       Year([tbl_expense].[exp_inv_date]) AS yr,
       Month([tbl_expense].[exp_inv_date]) AS mth
FROM tbl_expense
GROUP BY Year([tbl_expense].[exp_inv_date]), Month([tbl_expense].[exp_inv_date])
HAVING (((Year([tbl_expense].[exp_inv_date]))=" & current_year & "))
```

Below is the code that I currently implement to generate income & expense report:

```
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="80%" class="border" align="center">
    <tr bgcolor="#dddddd" >
       <td width="10%" align="center" class="border"><font class="bold">Month (th)</font></td>
        <td width="10%" align="center" class="border"><font class="bold">Year</font></td>                            
        <td  width="20%" class="border" align="center"><font class="bold">Total (Baht)</font></td>
        <td  width="20%" class="border" align="center"><font class="bold">Vat Total (Baht)</font></td>
        <td  width="20%" class="border" align="center"><font class="bold">Gross Total (Baht)</font></td>
        <td  width="20%" class="border" align="center"><font class="bold red">Expense (Baht)</font></td>                            
    </tr>
    <%

if rsBill.eof  then 
    call displayNotFoundRecord
Else
        Dim Cmonth, CLoop
        Cmonth = 1
        CLoop = 1

    Do while  Not rsBill.EOF    
                dim color 
                        y = n mod 2
                            if y > 0 then
                                color = "EFF4FA" 
                            else 
                                color =  "ffffff"
                            end if              
%>                    
    <tr  bgcolor="#<%=color%>">
         <td align="center"><%=rsBill.Fields.item("month")%></td>
         <td align="center"><%=current_year%></td>       
   <%
        Dim SumOfbill_total, SumOfVat_total, SumOfAll
        SumOfbill_total = rsBill.Fields.item("bill_total")
        SumOfVat_total = rsBill.Fields.item("vat_total")
        SumOfAll = SumOfbill_total + SumOfVat_total

    %>               


 <td align="right" style="padding-right:5%"><%=formatnumber(SumOfbill_total,2)%></td>
 <td align="right" style="padding-right:5%"><%=formatnumber(SumOfVat_total,2)%></td>

  <td align="right" style="padding-right:5%" class="blue"><%=formatnumber(SumOfAll,2)%></td>
  <td align="right" style="padding-right:5%;" class="red">
<%
    if rsExp.eof  then 
        response.write "No matches."
    Else
        Do while  Not rsExp.EOF 

                                            if rsExp.Fields.item("mth") = rsBill.Fields.item("month") then
                                    %>                            
                                                <%=formatnumber(rsExp.Fields.item("SumOfexp_amt"),2)%> 
                                    <%
                                            end if
                                    %>                                               

                                     <%
                                        rsExp.movenext
                                        Cmonth = Cmonth + 1
                                             n = n + 1

                                    %>

                                    <%
                                        Loop 'end rsExp Loop                                        
                                    End if   'end of rsExp

                                        SumOfYear = SumOfAll + SumOfYear                                                                
                                        rsExp.movefirst
%>                                  
                            </td>
                         </tr>   <!-- end of loop table -->      
<%                                                       
                                        rsBill.movenext 
    Loop
    rsBill.movefirst    

End if
%>                    
                        <tr bgcolor="#FFFFCC">
                            <td colspan="4" align="right">Gross Total </td>
                            <td align="right" style="padding-right:5%" class="green bold"><%=formatnumber(SumOfYear,2)%></td>
                            <td align="right" style="padding-right:5%" class="red bold"><%=formatnumber(rsSumExp.Fields.item("SumOfexp"),2)%></td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
```

Comment: @hypetech, this is 7.23am. my time and checking this post is the first thing i do when i work up. I didn't see how i ignore someone's attempt. In contrast i'm so appreciate all the help so much. Anyway on this post i think i've already show my effort to solve my problem. If you read all my code, you would see it work!!. However, as I wrote on the post , i need more effective way to come up with the less-consume-resource report. Pls try to understand people in optimistic way. We are come here to help each other , don't we??

Answer (score 0):

The [UNION set operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) is what I have used in the past.  This might create a gargantuan query, that may or may not work.

```
select sum(tbt.bill_total) as bill_total,
       iif(sum_vat_total is null, 0, sum_vat_total) as vat_total,
       iif(sum_vat_total is null, 0, sum_vat_total) + sum(bill_total) as sum_of_all,
       month(showndate) as [month]
from tbl_bill_total tbt
    left join (select sum(vat_total) as sum_vat_total, month(showndate) as [month]
               from tbl_vat_bill_total
               where if_paid = true
                 and year([showndate]) =" & current_year & "
               group by month(showndate)) tvt on tvt.month = month(tbt.showndate)
where year([showndate]) =" & current_year & "
group by month(showndate), sum_vat_total
UNION ALL
SELECT Sum(tbl_expense.exp_amt) AS SumOfexp_amt,
       Year([tbl_expense].[exp_inv_date]) AS yr,
       Month([tbl_expense].[exp_inv_date]) AS mth
FROM tbl_expense
GROUP BY Year([tbl_expense].[exp_inv_date]), Month([tbl_expense].[exp_inv_date])
HAVING (((Year([tbl_expense].[exp_inv_date]))=" & current_year & "))
```

The only other method I might suggest is the programmic approach, store the results from the first query into an array, then append the results of the second query into the same array (ensure that you are using the same table columns), then output or use the array?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. However when i run this sql it said "The number of columns in the two selected tables or queries of an union query do not match."

Comment: Yes, you can only union two queries that select the same columns.  Otherwise why would you combine the queries at all?   Sounds like the programmatic approach is the best method for you.